# Show timestamp at end of <Text> in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

I want to show time stamp same as this screen shot in react native. I have flex with row direction. But if the line of content is increases time stamp is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a child text to the notification text. For example

```
<Text>{some_notification_text} <Text>{formatted_timestamp}</Text></Text>
```

this way even if the content size increases the timestamp will be always at the end. If this does not solve your problem please share your code.